# Python not able to get iotop output

Tags: python, monitoring

I am working on a python script which needs to read the output of iotop. But stdout appears to be blank. The goal is to have the output of iotop stored as a string which I can then later search and use. This is running on Ubuntu 16.04 w/ python 3.6. I am calling the script with "sudo python3.6 script.py" as iotop requires admin rights.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['iotop','-b','-n','1','-a','-k'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
try:
    outs, errs = p.communicate(timeout=15)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    p.kill()
    outs, errs = p.communicate()
returncode=p.returncode
print(outs.decode('UTF-8'))
```

Running this command in the bash terminal gives me the expected output. What am I doing wrong?

```
sudo iotop -b -n 1 -a -k
```

Comment: You missing `sudo` before `iotop` in list that passed to Popen

Comment: I am running the script with sudo, so any subprocess opened by the script should also have root privs, no?

Comment: If you're using shell=True, that you should pass your cmd args as string: `Popen('iotop -b -n 1 -a -k',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `shell=True` made the code work the way I wanted to.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['iotop','-b','-n','1','-a','-k'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

`"-n"` and `"1"` should be separate list elements

Comment: Perhaps but that does not appear to fix the issue